# React.memo always contains the same value on prevProps and nextProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component `JobItem`. In my parent container, I manage the state. Everything works fine except for the memoization because `prevProps` and `nextProps` attributes are always equal.

Here is my component:

```
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {

  console.log(prevProps.job_item.quantity)
  console.log(nextProps.job_item.quantity)

  return false
};

const JobItem = React.memo(props => {

  return (
        ....
  )

}, areEqual);

export default JobItem;
```

Here is my event handler:

```
handleItemChange = (item, event) => {

    item[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      job: this.state.job
    })

}
```

In my `areEqual` function, I must return false for the component to update because `nextProps.job_item.quantity` is always equal to `prevProps.job_item.quantity`. I assume this has something to do with my event handler but I am not sure how to fix this.

Here is an example of the quantity field that calls the handler by first passing an instance of the `job_item` and then the event itself which allows me to change the attribute `quantity` on the job item which is apart of the current state and then set the state to the currently modified state object. The state object contains a `job` which contains an array of `items`.

```
<TextField
      name={name}
      value={value}
      label={label}
      variant="outlined"
      type="number"
      onChange={e => handleItemChange(item, e)}
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Your `handleItemChange` handler makes no sense. You mutate the `item` argument, then just **set the state equal to itself**. So your state isn't going to change. Think we'll need more context

Comment: @Jayce444 I've added a bit of an explanation for this to the question.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), show us how props in `JobItem` used.

Answer (score 0):

you are changing the reference of the state when you are using this.setState()

if you know that job_item.quantity is always same.
check like this

```
JSON.stringfy(prevProps.job_item.quantity) === JSON.stringfy(nextProps.job_item.quantity)
```